# How to set up the conditions to test web pages for HTTP status codes 403, 404, 500, 503

Tags: http-status-code-404, weblogic12c, http-status-code-403, http-status-codes, http-status-code-503

I developed a web application with Java (Struts 2) and Web Experience Toolkit (WET - https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew), which is running on the WebLogic 12c server.
When any one of the HTTP status codes 403, 404, 500, 503 occurs, my web application will display a corresponding web page.
e.g. When the HTTP status code 503 occurs, my web application will display the web page 503.html.
How to set up or simulate the conditions to test my web application web pages for HTTP status codes 403, 404, 500, 503?
i.e. simulate the HTTP status codes 503, etc so as to test my web application UI to ensure that 503 is handled properly, assuming that the webserver works properly.

Comment: Are you asumming that your webserver works properly and trying to test the UI? Or are you trying to test that the status codes are returned when it should?

Comment: assuming that the webserver works properly and trying to test the UI.

Comment: If you want to test the html then you can manually render it and check it's looking at it should. But imo it would be better to set up a couple of tests that force your system to fail so that you can check you actually receive the proper status code when it does

Comment: How to set up a couple of HTTP status codes tests that force the system to fail?
Any blog, article, scripts or software?

Comment: I think it depends entirely in your system. I mean, with the 404 for example, if you have a database then you could request an item from it that you know that won't be present, and then you test that 404 is returned